# mips array not printing

Tags: arrays, loops, mips

```
main:
la $t3 array
loop:

la $a0, msg1 #output message
li $v0, 4
syscall
li $v0, 5 #read in user input
syscall
move $t0, $v0
beq  $t0, -99, endloop
beq  $t1,20,endloop #get user input up to 20 times 

addi $t1, $t1, 1
sw $t0,($t3)
addi $t3,$t3,4

b loop #loop until it reaches 20 

endloop:
li $v0,4
la $a0, msg2
syscall
li $v0, 1 
move $a0, $t1
syscall
li $v0, 4
la $a0, newline
syscall
li $t5, 0
#t1 counter 
#t3 array address
printloop:
beq $t5, $t1, printend
lw $a0,4($t3)
li $v0, 1
syscall
addi $t5, $t5, 1
addi $t3, $t3, 4
j printloop
printend:
```

}
before i move to adding array value i was trying to make sure that when user enters values its being stored into array. but i dont know if its being stores because when i print its only printing zeros. 
can anyone tell me if my array loop is wrong or my print loop.
Thanks,

Comment: _"but i dont know if its being stores"_ If you run the code in a simulator like SPIM or MARS you can easily see whether the values you expect get written to the memory locations you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty simple problem here.

Before the `printloop` you've forgotten to reload the starting address of `array` into `$t3`.

Add `la $t3 array` just before the `printloop` label.

Also, I don't know why you're loading at a 4 offset: `lw $a0,4($t3)`. Use a zero offset instead: `lw $a0,0($t3)`.